# Javascript: Jquery post requests are not working as expected

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, tomcat8

i do not go ahead since hours and i am pretty frustated because i cannot find my fault and/or misunderstanding of my failure:

I want to call the backend for json data - by the following sourcecode:

```
 function dosomething(type)  
 {
     $.post( "dosomethingontheserver", {type}, function( myjson ) { 
       // do something usefull with myjson data   
    }, 'json' )
   .done(function() {
     // just ignore  
   })    
   .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {      
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
      console.log("type "+type);       
   })   
   .always(function() {
     // alert( "finished for type="+type );   
   });  }
```

If this code is called via:

```
dosomething(0);
```

everything is all right. But if i call this twice like:

```
dosomething(0);
dosomething(1);
```

i get the following on the console:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data
>       Stack-Trace:
>       jQuery.parseJSON@code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:9011:10
>       ajaxConvert@code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:9335:19
>       done@de.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:9789:15
>       callback@code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:10311:8

It seems that the (first) request is canceled by the call from the second and the response is not (anymore) a json format. the server returns always a json format - so there is no error on server side. This won't happen if i spend some extra time - like an "alert('hello'); in the dosomething() function.

Any ideas/Hint why the sec. call will disrupt the first (ongoing) call?

Comment: Maybe the server can't handle multiple calls and throws an error? Have you tried logging to confirm that the server is returning the json data for both calls?

Comment: Good point. i'll check this ....

Comment: The server can handle multipe requests. the backend is a sevlet (in a tomcat 8) executed in eclipse environment. i put some debug-line in it - both requests are received and both responses are transmitted. Both responses have been replaced by a static string - so both responses are equal.

Comment: Funny: I added a Thead.sleep for the first incomming call (type==0) - the client did receive the sec. answer sooner as the first request - but the error stays the same.

Comment: Check what the response is for the post request in the dev console (Network tab in chrome). It might have something helpful.

Comment: uhhh.....  it is not the first request which is going wrong  - it is the second. both requests are returned with HTTP 200 status. But the answer content of the sec. request is empty (0 bytes). But the servlet states no error and tell me that the httpresponse-stream was suc. send.

Comment: now i raised the debug levels for the embedded tomcat:  on one request it returns no json but an internal error:  >java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)

Comment: i guess the tomcat server cannot send the answer to the client because the client has already terminated the call. Because this "indexoutofbounds" exception is thrown not in my code but in the jvm code for transmitting the answer to the output-stream....

Comment: You might want to add that to the question and update the tags. Apologies but I'm not much good when it comes to tomcat.

Comment: The question is: why terminates the sec. call in javascript the connection of the first call.   (the error above was caused from the very first call)

Comment: Also have a look at [`when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to make multiple sequential calls to the server.

Comment: and... if you instead just call `dosomething(1);`?

Comment: I found it. i'm such an idiot. In the servlet the variable for the outputstream was declared as "static". so the sec. call will modify that stream too.

Answer (score -1):

Try to specify content-type and accept-type

Comment: How? The called servlet will set it like:  servletResponse.setContentType("application/json"); and in the javascript it is set as "'json'"

Comment: There's no reason to set a contentType if the one you want to use is the default.

Answer (score -1):

Thank to all responses.

I found it. I'm such an idiot. In the servlet the variable for the outputstream was declared as "static". So the sec. call will modify that stream too which lead to a problem on concurrent requests.